# Glass Food Processor

Tags: equipment, blender, food-processing

I would like to know if anybody here might know of a glass food processor product name. I'm trying to avoid plastic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some commercial food processors are available with metal bowls, although these models may be quite expensive.

You may may also wish to consider that many tasks a food processor is used for can be performed with a blender which typically do come with a glass pitcher, or with an immersion blender.

Comment: Robot Coupe and Hobart are some that come to mind (in the US) that I've seen with metal bowls, but of course we're talking commercial food processors that are easily $1k+ for basic starter models like SAJ14SAJ touched on. Not sure I've ever seen a home use one with glass or metal, only blenders. It might be easier to look for specifically BPA-free (or whatever fancies you) plastic.

Comment: You can get immersion/stick blender with stainless steel shafts. They cost a lot more though

Comment: It can be hard to find good food processors or blenders with glass vessels. Due to the high power of better models, there is an increased shattering risk with glass...

Comment: Are you saying that whatever caused the shattering of the glass would not faze a plastic vessel?

Comment: @Trancot Plastic is indeed much more shatter-resistant than glass; it tends to crack rather than actually shattering. You can compensate with thick glass, but if it does break, it's much more dangerous than plastic, especially in this case - it would likely shatter while the food processor is on, so the shards could get thrown all over.